# dojox mobile accordion using dojo mvc not working

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I tried to create dojox mobile accordion using dojox mvc repeat and group. i even tried using removeRepeatNode:true in data-dojo-props of dojox.mvc.Repeat and i get a JS error that

dojo/parser::parse() error
TypeError: b._at is undefined

Im using dojo 1.9

can any one help regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same question in [dojo-interest mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.dojo.user/78832). [dojox/mvc/Repeat](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc/Repeat.html) is a deprecated module. [dojox/mvc/WidgetList](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc/WidgetList.html) supercedes it.

Below code demonstrates how [dojox/mobile/Accordion](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/Accordion.html) can be used with [dojox/mvc/WidgetList](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc/WidgetList.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Accordion</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"
            data-dojo-config="mblThemeFiles: ['base', 'Accordion']"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: 1, parseOnLoad: 0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/_base/declare",
                "dojox/mvc/at",
                "dojox/mobile/parser",
                "dojox/mobile/Accordion",
                "dojox/mvc/WidgetList",
                "dojox/mvc/Output",
                "dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin",
                "dojox/mobile",
                "dojox/mobile/ContentPane"
            ], function(declare, at, parser, Accordion){
                declare("my.Accordion", Accordion, {
                    addChild: function(widget, index){
                        this.inherited(arguments, [widget, index * 2]);
                    }
                })
                window.at = at;
                window.model = [
                    {title: "foo", content: "Foo", selected: true},
                    {title: "bar", content: "Bar"},
                    {title: "baz", content: "Baz"}
                ];
                parser.parse();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-dojo-type="my.Accordion"
            data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/WidgetList,dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
            data-dojo-props="children: model"
            data-mvc-child-type="dojox/mobile/ContentPane"
            data-mvc-child-mixins="dojox/mvc/Templated"
            data-mvc-child-props="label: at(this.target, 'title'), selected: at(this.target, 'selected')">
            <script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
                <div>
                    <span data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Output"
                        data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'content')"></span>
                </div>
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Some tricks are:

- The way [dojox/mobile/Accordion](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/Accordion.html) inserts the title portion does not work well
  with how [dojox/mvc/WidgetList](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc/WidgetList.html) calls dojox/mobile/Accordion.addChild().
  You'll need to double the index to work around it.
- Given Dojo template does not allow [data-dojo-type](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#object-types), [data-dojo-mixins](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#data-dojo-mixins) or
  [data-dojo-props](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#parser-parameters) in the root node of template, you'll need to specify those
  in data-mvc-child-type, data-mvc-child-mixins and data-mvc-child-props in
  where dojox/mvc/WidgetList is declared.

See [my mailing list reply](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.dojo.user/78832/focus=78838) for more.

Best,
Akira

Comment: Thanks for user answer, but i still have some issues with it in worklight. The code in fiddle is working fine but I'm working on an worklight 6 mobile app and now I'm facing different issue with it. When ever in my project i require dojox.mvc.WidgetList I get a server error 500 at _TemplatedMixin.js. I've tried this before also and the result was same. Even if i dont use dojox.mvc.WidgetList anywhere in my html and I just require it, I get that error

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Given you said the error happens loading _TemplatedMixin.js, you might want to see if any template widget works in your environment. 2) Given it happens with a specific product (Worklight) you may want to contact support of that product.

Comment: I have a similar problem, except that i have multiple children that should be in each accordion.  The fiddle seems to only work if there is a 1on1 relationship.  Is there a way to do a second loop for children? can you have a wigetlist be a child of a wiget list? right now i have a bunch of listitems seperated by category and im using dojox.dtl to do it.  were trying to migrate our code to mvc